# Interval of convergence, pointwise and absolute

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Give the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(x + 10)^n}{3^n (n+1)},$$ find the intervals which result in point-wise and absolute convergence.

Applying the root test we have,

$$L(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \dfrac{(x + 10)^n}{3^n (n+1)} \right|} = \left| \dfrac{x+10}{3} \right| \dfrac{1}{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^{1/n}} = \left| \dfrac{x+10}{3} \right|.$$

The series is absolutely convergent when $L(x) < 1$ so, 
$$\left| \dfrac{x+10}{3} \right| < 1 \implies I_{\rm abs} = (-13, -7).$$

Where $I_{\rm abs}$ is the interval for which the series converges absolutely.

Given that absolute convergence $\implies$ point-wise convergence, is it sufficient to just check if the series converges on the boundary for the point-wise case? i.e. taking $x = -13, -7$ in the above we find $I_{\rm pntw} = [-13, -7]$ for the point-wise interval. Is it correct?

Comment: The series diverges to $+\infty$ for $x=-7$ (it is the harmonic series), whereas converges for $x=-13$ (using the Leibnitz criterion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in finding the radius of convergence and the statement that is is absolutely convergent  for $$ \left| \dfrac{x+10}{3} \right| < 1 \implies I_{\rm abs} = (-13, -7).$$

When it comes to the endpoint,  notice that the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(x + 10)^n}{3^n (n+1)}$$ does not converge at $x=-7$ since the harmonic series diverges.
It does converge at $x=-13$ since the alternating harmonic  series converges.

Please modify your interval of convergence accordingly.

Comment: Yes I made a small mistake when doing that. Thanks. Just to confirm though: 'checking the end points' in this way is equivalent to checking point-wise convergence? (assuming absolute convergence has been established).

Comment: Yes you just plug the endpoint for $x$ and make a decision.

Comment: Just to learn more, to check for point-wise convergence, why do we only need to check the endpoints after knowing the interval for absolute convergence?